# Debug window toolbar console missing arrows

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I am trying to debug a simple program in Python with PyCharm debugger but when I put a break point and run debugger the arrows such as "Step Into" or "Step Over" doesn't show so I can't move on with debugging. The last time I used PyCharm I didn't have this problem and I don't believe I did anything that can change the debugger.

[image: screenshot of debug window]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to uninstall it from the control panel and download it again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you explain why you think an entire reinstallation is necessary, or is this just a guess?

Answer (score 2):

The part of the toolbar you're refering to with the *"Step Over"* <kbd>F8</kbd>, *"Step Into"* <kbd>F7</kbd> icons is called the *"Debug Tool Window Top Toolbar"* or the [Stepping Toolbar](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debug-tool-window.html#steptoolbar). It can be enabled/disabled cliking on the cog on the right side of the toolbar and choosing `Show Toolbar`.

[image: screenshot of debug window]

You can also configure the icons individually by going to `Settings` `>` `Apperance and Behavior` `>` `Menus and Toolbars` `>` `Debug Tool Window Top Toolbar` `>` `Add Action` and using `Choose Actions to Add`.

[image: screenshot of settings menus and toolbars]